# Correctly depicting spider anatomy

Tags: anatomy, arachnology

First off, my specific query: When depicting a spider - be it in a picture or in textual/verbal description - should the chelicerae be always be placed so that they project outwards from the ventral side of the cephalothorax's anteriormost part, like in [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spider_internal_anatomy-en.svg)? Or are there other possibilities (e.g. attached by their basal undersides to the front of the cephalothorax) that are still anatomically correct?

Second, a more general inquiry: Are there any common pitfalls in depiction of spider anatomy that I should be aware of?